# Sorting a numbered table of contents and the contents associated with it

Tags: python, python-2.x, hash-map

Given a numbered table of contents with headers and the content of each section, I wanted to sort them correctly according to only the numeric value.

The first challenge: section numbers can be tricky to sort (i.e. `sorted(["1.1.1", "1.1.2", "1.1.10"])` results in: `["1.1.1", "1.1.10", "1.1.2"]` which is alphabetically correct, but not what I want).

Thankfully, this problem is already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37596095).

Using similar logic, I want to make an `OrderedDict` that has for key a list of headers (where each header is a string concatenation of the section number and its title) and for value the contents of each section.

I came up with the following solution, but I want some feedback, because it seems convoluted (although it seems to be doing what I want):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

headers = ['4.2.10 Context 4', '4.2.11 Context 5', '4.2.0 Context 1', '4.2.1 Context 2', '4.2.2 Context 3']
sections = ['C4', 'C5', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3']


def section_sort(t):
    section = t[0]
    numbering_pattern = re.compile('\d.\d[.\d]*')

    if numbering_pattern.match(section.split(' ')[0]):
        s_nbr = section.split(' ')[0]
        return [int(_) for _ in s_nbr.split('.')]

contents = OrderedDict(sorted(zip(headers, sections), key=section_sort))

for k, v in contents.items():
    print('{header}\n\t{section}'.format(header=k, section=v))
```

Output:

> ```
> 4.2.0 Context 1
>   C1
> 4.2.1 Context 2
>   C2
> 4.2.2 Context 3
>   C3
> 4.2.10 Context 4
>   C4
> 4.2.11 Context 5
>   C5
> ```

What's your take on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *pre-compile the regular expression* outside of the function (even though the Python RegEx engine is smart enough and it is ["caching" the pattern under-the-hood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452143/771848)), use `.match()` and `.groups()` methods, which would look a bit more pythonic and concise:

```
SECTION_PATTERN = re.compile(r'(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)')


def section_sort(section):
    """Section number key sort function."""
    match = SECTION_PATTERN.match(section[0])
    return [int(item) for item in match.groups()] if match else None
```

And, if you want to get a **performance boost**, you can avoid using regular expressions and go for a split by space followed by a split by a dot:

```
def section_sort(section):  # TODO: error handling?
    """Section number key sort function."""
    return [int(item) for item in section[0].split()[0].split(".")]
```

Some `timeit` metrics:

```
In [1]: %timeit OrderedDict(sorted(zip(headers, sections), key=section_sort_regex))
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.6 µs per loop

In [2]: %timeit OrderedDict(sorted(zip(headers, sections), key=section_sort_no_regex))
100000 loops, best of 3: 12 µs per loop
```

---

Note the use of `section` variable name instead of the less meaningful `t`.

As a side note, you are misusing the `_` variable name - it is agreed that `_` is a [conventional way to name "throw-away" variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163/771848) - variables that are not actually used. In your case, this is your loop variable that you are passing to `int()` for conversion. You should've chosen a better meaningful variable name for it.

Comment: Really appreciated both answers to this question. However, I just wanted to point out (and I did leave that out of my question) that there is a use case where not all my headers number contain 3 numbers (in fact they can contain from 2 to x number, hence my original regex `'\d.\d[.\d]*'`. Thanks for all the other performance and code convention advice. They are noted!

Answer (score 5):

Just a performance tip. The function section_sort is called multiples times and you are compiling the RegEx each time. Also you are using section.split() twice in the function to get the same value. You can save these values in vars. The code would be like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

headers = ['4.2.10 Context 4', '4.2.11 Context 5', '4.2.0 Context 1', '4.2.1 Context 2', '4.2.2 Context 3']
sections = ['C4', 'C5', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3']
numbering_pattern = re.compile('\d.\d[.\d]*')

def section_sort(t):
    section = t[0]

    snbr = section.split(' ')[0]
    if numbering_pattern.match(snbr):
        return [int(_) for _ in s_nbr.split('.')]

contents = OrderedDict(sorted(zip(headers, sections), key=section_sort))

for k, v in contents.items():
    print('{header}\n\t{section}'.format(header=k, section=v))
```

Comment: I think you've introduced a bug by using `int()` instead of `int(_)`. Also, the Python RegEx engine is [caching the pattern internally](http://stackoverflow.com/a/452143/771848).

Comment: Thanks @alecxe, now it´s fixed. It´s good to know that it is cached (I didn´t know that), but there is no point to call the function either way.